# Outlook add-in Office object is undefined

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I'm having a really hard time trying to find any documentation for Outlook add-ins development.

I want to use the `Office` object to access the current message attachment files from within the add-in, but `Office` is always undefined.
I have the following block in my manifest, as it's shown on the website:

```
<OfficeApp
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
    xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
    xsi:type="MailApp">
```

And also the following line in my script before attempting to access the `Office` object:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My requirements are just

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

After just defining those the `Office` object seems to exist [on the official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements):

```
if ( Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported( RequirementSetName, VersionNumber ) )
```

What am I missing? I still get the `undefined` error for `Office`, and haven't found anything about how to make it work.

Thank you so so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Office.js documentation ...

> If you fail to include an **Office.initialize** event handler, your add-in may raise an error when it starts.

I believe the "[Checking the load status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/loading-the-dom-and-runtime-environment#checking-the-load-status)" document will be great way to start.

Comment: Thank you! I had run over that page a couple times already but it didn't work because I also didn't know how the flow works here, but it makes sense to me now (maybe I'm still wrong, but at least not as much as before) that the Office object only exists inside that function and inside the functions that are called from within the Office.initialize body, not just anywhere in the script after the Office.initialize declaration.